# Unable to display result of camera activity in ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-camera, capture

Basically what I'm trying to do is create a simple app that uses the default camera app to take a picture, then I want to display that image in a new activity within an ImageView, but everything I've tried has resulted in

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/imageToProcess.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

I've included the correct permissions (maybe even too many) in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and I'm also manually requesting permissions if need be in the main activity:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
    }
    if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    }
    if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    }
}
```

so I don't think the issue is with read/write permissions.

In my main activity's xml file, I've created a button with an onClick listener that calls the following method:

```
public void openCamera(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "imageToProcess.jpg");
    imgUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    intent.putExtra("imgUri", imgUri.toString());
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}
```

Here's the onActivityResult() method I defined to create a new intent and pass the uri to the new activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if(requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Intent camResult = new Intent(this, ShowCameraResult.class);
        camResult.putExtra("imgUri", imgUri.toString());
        startActivity(camResult);
    }
}
```

NOTE: imgUri and TAKE_PICTURE are defined at the top of the class as `protected static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;` and `private Uri imgUri;`

Lastly, here is my ShowCameraResult activity

```
public class ShowCameraResult extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Bitmap mImageBitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_camera_result);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        String filePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("imgUri");
        Log.d("ShowCameraResult", "directory: " + filePath);
        try {
            mImageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(filePath));
            imageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The Log.d method call above returns

```
ShowCameraResult: directory: file:///storage/emulated/0/imageToProcess.jpg
```

This leads me to believe that the image result from the camera isn't actually being saved into my imageToProcess.jpg file, but I could be very wrong as this is the first real android project I've worked on.

So my question is: **Where did I go wrong?**

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: test it on device not on emulator

Comment: @Dhara I'm testing on a Galaxy S5

Comment: its a bug in Samsung test on other device

Comment: @DharaPatel Its not a Samsung bug.  Its returning a valid file path

Answer (score 0):

ITs returning a file, not a content resolver uri.  Just decode the file with BitmapFactory.

Comment: It's returning the URI of a file.  Use BitmapFactory.decodeFile to get the Bitmap for the file.  Then display that.  No content resolvers needed, it isn't returning a UR.  Its storing the file right where you asked it to in your intent.

Comment: Oh and side note-  you don't need camera permission to launch the camera intent.  Only if you plan on taking the picture in your app.